# Restore old Win+Tab behaviour in Windows 10 post April 2018

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to restore the old `win+tab` behaviour after the Windows 10 April 2018 update? Or, at the very least, to disable the new one's animations?

---

After the April 2018 updated automatically installed itself on my PC, I immediately set about disabling the *timeline* feature in three places:

1. Disabling *Show suggestions occasionally in Timeline* under Multi-tasking settings.
2. Disabling *Let Windows collect my activities from this PC* under Activity History.
3. Disabling *Let Windows synchronise my activities from this PC to the cloud* under Activity History. (Already disabled -- I do not use a Microsoft Account)

This cleaned up the `win+tab` experience (what is the proper name?) somewhat but, sadly, did not restore the old one. With timeline disabled, the new `win+tab` experience  looks as follows:

[image: Win+Tab post April 2018 Update]

I have some severe criticisms:

1. Unlike `alt+tab` and the old `win+tab` view, tasks are now shown at the top-left instead of the centre. This is inconsistent and rather annoying on a big monitor.
2. Desktop thumbnails are now also at the top, not the bottom, and are now left aligned. Inconsistent with the old behaviour and also inconsistent with the default taskbar location: the bottom of the screen. Mostly, being left-aligned leads to a lot of mouse movement to click them.
3. It does not respect animation settings so pressing `win+tab` now punishes the user with two slow and annoying animations. The first, when you change from the desktop to the new view, is tolerable. But the second, upon leaving the new view and returning to the desktop, is very slow and awkward.

I tried to disable just the animations but failed. I had to disable all animation settings in Windows, again, because the update reset them (I work far too fast for animations to be anything less than extremely aggravating. Most specifically: the sheering animation when one switches virtual desktops looks horrendous on a 32" workstation monitor!)

Animation settings, I have found, now exist in two places:

1. The New: '*Show Animations in Windows*'
2. The old: System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance Options -> Visual Effects

[image: My Performance Options]

I disabled all the animations for which I could find settings but the sliding/sheering when entering and exiting the new `win+tab` view persists.

And so, first prize, I'd like to restore the old behaviour. Second prize, I'd like to kill the animations. Please help!

Comment: Windows 10 is a continually evolving OS, there are going to be changes no one likes, but there is most likely no way to change what Microsoft has baked into the OS.

Comment: I'd suggest including the actual Win10 version in questions like this one, since most people can't automatically know which version the April 2018 feature update bumps you to.  Since the original question was a while ago, I looked it up:  should be 1803).